# Not able to display multiple data from rails 3.2 backend(postgresql) in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently doing a project for a Library Management system.I have five tables in the project.All of them are interlinked that is they are referencing each other.

The tables which I am working on is `Admin`,`Books`,`Library_Locations`,`Users` and `Categories`

```
Books is referencing user,categories and admin .User is referencing library_location
```

I have created the model and controllers for all of them.I want to know if I can create a view such that if I click on book_id,I can get the details of user,category and admin.

My Books table is:-

```
id serial NOT NULL,
  title character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  abstract character varying(255),
  isbn character varying(255),
  call_no character varying(255),
  reference_no character varying(255),
  category_id integer,
  library_location_id integer,
  author_first_name character varying(255),
  author_middle_name character varying(255),
  author_last_name character varying(255),
  image character varying(255),
  publisher character varying(255),
  edition character varying(255),
  book_location character varying(255),
  deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  total_num_copies integer,
  cost numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0.0,
  entered_by integer,
  last_updated_by integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT books_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

I have tried it on lov_names and values.The view is:-

```
<h3>lov Name</h3><br>
<div class="span3">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>    
<td>Lov Names-Id: </td><td><%= params[:id] %></td>
<tr><td>Lov Names-Name:</td><td> <%= LovName.where('id = ?', params[:id]).pluck(:name)[0] %></td></tr>
<tr><td>Lov Values-Description:</td><td> <%= LovName.where('id = ?', params[:id]).pluck(:description)[0] %></td></tr>
</tr>


</table>
</div>
</br>

   <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">

 <tr><th>lov_value id.</td><th>lov_value Name</th><th>lov_value</th><th>Sequence</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>
<% @lov_value.each do |p| %>
<tr>
<td><%= p.id %> <br></td>
<td><%= p.lov_name_id %> <br></td>
<td><%= p.lov_value %> <br></td>
<td><%= p.sequence %> <br></td>

<td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'lov_value_edit', :id => p.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'lov_value_delete', :id => p.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this lov_value?" } %></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<br/>

<p class="btn btn-primary "><%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'index'} %></p>
<p class="btn btn-primary "><%= link_to 'Add New lov_values', {:action => 'add_values'} %></p>
```

My Books.rb snippet:-

```
has_many :book_holds
has_many :book_transactions

belongs_to :admin, :foreign_key => 'last_updated_by'
belongs_to :admin, :foreign_key => 'entered_by'

belongs_to :library_location
belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :user
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion as to how to implement this

Comment: what did google tell you when you searched? Do you have a book on rails?

Comment: The columns of your books table is really not necessary here. What we need to see is some of the view code you've tried (.erb or .haml, probably), so we can get you past the obstacle that has you stuck.

Comment: I think we also need some lines from your model.rb files. Specifically, your relationship declarations like `has_many` and `belongs_to` or even `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Knowing those will help immensely.

Comment: @AustinMullins,I have updated the question.Can you please help

Comment: The ERB above looks like it just came from a `generate scaffold` command. What exactly were you trying to do? What data do you want to see?

Comment: @AustinMullins.i want to display data from three different tables in a single view.Also in the above erb file i am getting data from two table that is lov_names and lov_values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably over-thinking the issue, or maybe you didn't read [Michael Hartl's phenomenal Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) which is 100% free online (and there are inexpensive [print](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321832051) and [kindle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008RN1SJO) editions as well).

Accessing the different values you need should happen in the *controller* class, and displaying the data should happen in the view. So your controller needs to look like:

### /app/controllers/books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController
  def index
   @books = Book.all
  end

  def show
   @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   @category = @book.category
   @lastUpdatedBy = @book.last_updated_by
   @enteredBy = @book.entered_by
   @user = @book.user
  end

  # Any other methods (edit, destroy, create, new, etc.) go here
end
```

Now we define the view:

### /app/views/books/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @book.title %><h1>
<h2>By <%= @book.author %></h2>
<h3>Category: <%= @category.name %></h3>

<p> Current user: <%= @user.name %> </p>
<p> Last updated by: <%= @lastUpdatedBy.name %> </p>
<p> Entered by: <%= @enteredBy.name %> </p>
```